# What can I do to speed up the statistics module?

Tags: mysql, database, drupal, optimization

The insert statement in the statistics module is slowing our website down dramatically. As there are more rows inserted, the problem gets worse. When we truncated the table, the site sped up again. We would like to keep the data, but make it faster if possible.

```
 db_query("INSERT INTO {accesslog} (title, path, url, hostname, uid, sid, timer, timestamp) values('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %d, '%s', %d, %d)", strip_tags(drupal_get_title()), $_GET['q'], referer_uri(), ip_address(), $user->uid, session_id(), timer_read('page'), time());
```

Table structure:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| aid        | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sid        | varchar(64)      | NO   |     |         |                |
| title      | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| path       | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| url        | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hostname   | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| uid        | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| timer      | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| timestamp  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| uri        | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Rows (currently): 522,737
Type: MyISAM
Size: 127.4 MiB

Please let me know if you need additional information.

EDIT: I have done a little research on the engine types and it seems I am getting mixed messages on which is better to use in this case myisam or innodb... can anyone answer that?

EDIT 2: Here are the indexes on the table:

```
+-----------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| accesslog |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | aid         | A         |      522858 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| accesslog |          1 | accesslog_timestamp |            1 | timestamp   | A         |      522858 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| accesslog |          1 | uid                 |            1 | uid         | A         |         164 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

Edit 3: What my boss and I have decided to do is not log the search engine bots. I'm still trying to figure out the best way to do this. If you have any ideas please let me know.

Comment: [Use Google Analytics Instead of the Statistics Module](http://activelamp.com/blog/use-google-analytics-instead-statistics-module)

Comment: This may be an option, but it's not up to me. I still need ways to speed this up.

Comment: @Clive Or [Piwik](http://piwik.org/).

Comment: Try breaking down each of the elements in the query (calls to `ip_address()`, `timer_read()`, etc.) and see if those are causing the bottlenecks. If they are, find a better way of obtaining that data. If they're not, either put the site on a faster server or truncate the table regularly, that's about all you can do

Comment: @JamWaffles: Wasn't aware of that one cheers for the heads up :)

Comment: We actually use this table for other things besides analytics... like displaying the user's last viewed items.

Comment: Still, using almost any other solution for achieving your goal would be a far better option than statistics module, as far as performance is concerned. Maybe add a NoSQL store to simply store uid + time stamp + node visited, and do it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try from the db side.Just make sure you have a backup somewhere.

Is that table heavily indexed? remove some will give you a boost.

> "We actually use this table for other things besides analytics... like
>   displaying the user's last viewed items. "

given mixed read/write, you can also try change to innodb engine, or split it.

@edit1&2: Try it out (make sure you backup twice) `ALTER TABLE name TYPE = [InnoDB | MyISAM]`, you might want to try run some db optimization [scripts](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl) and fine tune some db config as well.

@edit2: based on your update, you table looks fine to me. and the bottle neck seems a lot more likely on the drupal side getting the variable from other tables.
You can compare the speed by timing the insert query run in cml and drupal.

some additional [material](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html)

Comment: What do you mean by heavily indexed? And what do you mean by split it?

Comment: I concur on switching to innodb, since this is a write-heavy table. The indexing shouldn't be too bad, if you haven't added any indexes Drupal did not. Also, splitting the table would be more hassle than its worth.

Comment: just to expand what @gerrlingguy said, index will increase read speed at the cost of write speed, so if you have a lot unnecessary indexes, the insert query would be quite slow.  Split table refer to [patitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/partitioning.html). This solution might be a bit overkill ATM, however once your db grows significant bigger, it will give you some solid performance boost.